# Dexiejs advanced search

Tags: dexie

I am building a inventory app. I have few search fields (part no, manufacturer etc..). I have been trying to build the search based on the input fields. But nothing seems to be working.
Things i tried.

```
db.version(1).stores({
  parts: "++id,partno,description,category,manufacturer,cost,qty,add_date,condition,location"
});
```

Search 1:

```
var searchParams = { 'partno': 'md101', 'manufacturer': 'apple', 'category': 'notebook'}
```

Search 1:

```
var searchParams = { 'condition': 'new', 'category': 'notebook'}
```

Worked, but case sensitive. can i make it case insensitive?:

```
db.parts.where(search);
```

Failed:

```
var fields = Object.keys(search);
var values = Object.values(search)
db.parts.where(fields).equals(values);
```

Please help me to figure this out. Documentation didn't help

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.parts.where({
  partno: 'md101',
  manufacturer: 'apple',
  category: 'notebook'
}).toArray().then(result => console.log(result);
```

The above query will make an logical and between the criterias and match exact.

To match by case, try the following :

```
db.parts.where('partno').equalsIgnoreCase('md101')
  .and(part=>
    part manufacturer &&
    part manufacturer.toLowerCase() === 'apple' &&
    part.category &&
    part.category.toLowerCase() === 'notebook')
 .toArray()
  .then(result => console.log (result))
```

What we do here is utilizing the most spread index only and filter out the rest manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point. Just updated the answer right now with another sample

Comment: Another strategy would be to store the values in lowercase. If so, you might also considering defining a compound index of the three props to optimize the object - query further.